# JSON to .CSV in PHP

Tags: php, json

My JSON data is given below. It does not have [] or separated by comma which make it difficult for me to decode.

```
$jsondata = 
  '{"firstname": "user1", "lastname": "user1", "phonenumber": "12314", "notes": "[]", "lastvisited": "2021-05-12 21:49:15"}
  {"firstname": "user2", "lastname": "user2", "phonenumber": "12345", "notes": "[]", "lastvisited": "2021-04-24 20:48:58"}';
```

My try:

```
$jsonans = json_decode($jsondata, true);
print_r($jsonans);
```

Any code suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: That's not valid JSON you've shown. Where is this JSON coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to get valid JSON.  If this was stored somewhere as invalid and these are the only problems then just fix them:

```
$jsondata = '['.preg_replace('/}\s+{/', '}, {', $jsondata).']';
$result   = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

If you're sure that there is only one space between `}` and `{` then faster than regex:

```
$jsondata = '['.str_replace('} {', '}, {', $jsondata).']';
```

Then just loop `$result` and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: This works perfect. As you mentioned I will ask for the valid JSON for a permanent solution.